# Merging two gulp streams

Tags: gulp

I am trying to merge two gulp sources as follows:

```
gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function () {

  var sb = gulp.src([
    paths.bower + "jquery/jquery.js",
    paths.bower + "angular/angular.js"
  ])
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.vnd));

 var sm = gulp.src([
   paths.scripts.vnd + "jquery.js",
   paths.scripts.vnd + "angular.js"
 ])
  .pipe(concat("app.js"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dst))
  .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dst));

  return merge(sb, sm);

});
```

Somehow only the first one is executed.

However, if I move the second one to another task with dependency on build then both are executed ...

Am I doing the merging the wrong way?

**UPDATE 1**

I updated my task to build both LESS files and JS files so I have:

```
var
  gulp = require("gulp"),  
  fs = require("fs"),
  merge = require("merge2"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  flatten = require("gulp-flatten"),
  less = require('gulp-less'),
  minify = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var paths = {
  bower: "./bower_components/",
  scripts: {
    app: "./" + "/scripts/app/",
    dst: "./" + "/scripts/dst/",
    vnd: "./" + "/scripts/vnd/"
  },
  styles: {
    app: "./" + project.webroot + "/styles/app/",
    dst: "./" + project.webroot + "/styles/dst/"
  }
};

gulp.task("build", function () {

  var sbm = gulp.src([
    paths.styles.app + "*.less",
    paths.styles.vnd + "*.less"
  ])
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(minify())
  .pipe(concat("app.css"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dst))
  .pipe(rename("app.min.css"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dst));

  var scb = gulp.src(
    [
      paths.bower + "jquery/jquery.js",
      paths.bower + "angular/angular.js"
    ])
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.vnd));

  var scm = gulp.src(
    [
      paths.scripts.vnd + "jquery.js",
      paths.scripts.vnd + "angular.js"
    ])
   .pipe(concat("app.js"))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dst))

   return merge(sbm, scb, scm);

});
```

Somehow, this only executes sbm ... Does anyone knows why?

I also tried @topleft's suggestion but when including the LESS tasks at the end the app.min.js file get's the Less code in it ...

Comment: It is in the docs, see the following [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md)

Comment: I followed that. Is not what i am doing on my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this with merge2 plugin, that's how I do it

```
var merge = require('merge2');

gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function () {
  var sb = gulp.src([
    paths.bower + "jquery/jquery.js",
    paths.bower + "angular/angular.js"
  ])
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.vnd));

 var sm = gulp.src([
   paths.scripts.vnd + "jquery.js",
   paths.scripts.vnd + "angular.js"
 ])

   return merge(sb, sm)
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dst))
    .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dst));

});
```

as an example, here is how I merge my two LESS streams : (one is unCSS'ed, the other is not)

```
/* ===== LESS START ===== */
gulp.task('less', function() {
    // Get static styles
    var streamMain = gulp.src([
        srcAssets + '/less/**/*.less',
        srcAssets + '!/less/**/interactive.less',])
        // Convert to CSS
        .pipe(less())
        // Remove unused CSS rules
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: [dest + '/index.html']
        }))

    // Get dynamic styles
    var streamEvents = gulp.src(srcAssets + '/less/global/interactive.less')
        // Convert to CSS
        .pipe(less())

    // Merge dynamic and static styles
    return merge(streamMain, streamEvents)
        // Concatenate in a single file
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        // Remove all comments
        .pipe(stripCssComments({
            all: true
        }))
        // Autoprefixer for browser compatibility
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        // Compression
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        // Output file
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/css'));
});
/* ===== LESS END ===== */
```

Comment: your suggestion works if I only build the JS files ... But if I also build the LESS code in the same task I get a few problems. I just update my code. Do you have any idea how to solve this. I don't understand why simply using return merge(sbm, scb, scm); won't work.